# Why am I seeing two JPG files instead of RAW + JPG with a Canon 1100D?

Tags: raw, troubleshooting, canon-1100d

I have a Canon 1100D and I started taking pictures in the RAW+JPG mode. For some reason when I open my files on my PC I see 2 files, but both of them are JPG (they even have the same size). What is the problem and where is the RAW file?

Comment: What are the names of the two files you see?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible that your version of Windows in not up to date and does not contain the codec's required to support the Canon RAW format. Windows did not, until recently, have this built into the system.

Try the Microsoft Codec Pack, which should give you the ability to show and use the RAW files.

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=26829

or

http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/windows_vista/cameras/eos_slr_camera_systems/canon_raw_codec_software

Also, if you have the necessary RAW support, in this case, .cr2 files, both images will display similar images in preview. The RAW file embeds a JPG image within it, in order to display a preview for use in such things as Windows Explorer or Mac Finder.  If you have Windows configured to hide file extensions for known file types, you may see a RAW file behaving as a JPG. If you do not see .jpg at the end of the file, this may be the issue. Turn on file extensions to confirm that these are indeed .cr2 files.

Comment: That codec pack doesn't support newer cameras though. The newest Canon DSLR in that list is 550D, which came out 2 years ago. No 1100D, 60D, 600D, D7000, G12, S95, D3100, D5100, and some more of other brands.

Comment: For purposes of the OS recognizing the RAW file, this should work. Editing may present other issues, but your editing software (other than MS) should provide that needed support.

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't know there _was_ a Windows Imaging Component (WIC).  It may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me. After using the camera for a while I found when I switched to Jpeg+Raw I copied the files over to the folder on my PC and had two jpegs.

This puzzled me as I knew I had used that once before and my PC had no problem with raw files, and I had .CR2 files on my hard drive to prove it. I was convinced the Camera was not now recording the raw files properly.

However the issue was resolved when I used the EOS utility software to transfer the images to my PC.

This time they appeared as they should, each a pair of images, one raw and one jpeg.

Seems it was the drag and drop from the camera as a folder in Windows explorer that was the problem.

Hope that helps someone.